# PCB Newbie Stackup understand questions

Tags: differential, impedance-matching, pcb-layers, stack-up, multi-layer

I want to design a board with 6 layers up to 1.8mm thickness,120ohm diff and 90ohm diff ,SE 50 ohm
and the manufacturer sent me this stackup:
[image]

1. 12 mil for SE-50ohm not too thick?
2. what is the material between layers 1 to 2?
3. what is the material between layers 2 to 3 ?
   how do you identify whether that is Prepag or Core?
   Every manufacturer has his unique symbols!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need thinner, get a different stackup. Tell the manufacturer to provide you with a different stackup because you need the 50Ohms to be thinner. The manufacturer calculated the stackup so it's up to him.
2. The material is a 1080 from the 185HR family from Isola, it's a prepreg.
3. That's the core, it's made of 3x7628 material: https://www.isola-group.com/wp-content/uploads/data-sheets/185hr-laminate-and-prepreg__Dk_Df_Tables.pdf